# Calculate length of radial intersecting a rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

In a rectangle like below, I need to calculate the length of any radial, from the center of the rectangle to where it intersects with the edge of the rectangle.  Further, the angle of the radial is expressed as bearing, in the degrees of a compass rose centered on the rectangle, with range 0 to 359.

So I'm looking for a function: radial length = f(width, height, bearing) where bearing is the angle measured from the vertical, as depicted by the colored examples on the diagram.
And, since I'm such a math dunce, I would be grateful if the solution could be expressed in terms of a popular programming language like Java, in addition to a mathematical expression.

I'm hoping for something more succinct than my own clumsy efforts shown below the diagram.

[image: rectangle]

```
var bearingMod90 = (((Math.floor(bearing/90))%2)==0) ? 90-(bearing % 90) : bearing % 90;
var radialLength;
if (bearingMod90 != 0)
 {
  var angle = height / width;
  radialLength = (bearingMod90>=angle) ? (height/Math.tan(this.toRad(bearingMod90)))/Math.cos(this.toRad(bearingMod90))
                                       : (width*Math.tan(this.toRad(bearingMod90)))/Math.sin(this.toRad(bearingMod90));
 }
  else { radialLength = height; }
```

Comment: welcome to MSE.

Comment: This question may be more suitable on stackoverflow.com if you're looking for an answer in terms of code. The general solution will be split into several different cases.

Comment: @flymike, I need to clarify the parameters, bearing is the angle of the compass right? Width and Height is of the rectangle. I do understand the return value. 

That being said, if you clarify this, I would gladly give you a java solution.

Comment: Good, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you divide it in 4 cases. This four cases is if bearing is within the right wall, top wall, left wall, bottom wall.

Below is a python code, should be easy to translate to c++ or java. If you need assistance with that, I'll work on it.

radialIntersect.py

> import math
>
> def radialIntersect(width, height, bearing):
>
> ```
> center = (width/2.0, height/2.0)
>
> #slope = y/x
>
> # Acquire corner angles
> cornerAngleTR = math.degrees(math.atan(center[1]/center[0]))
> cornerAngleBR = 360 - cornerAngleTR
> cornerAngleTL = 180 - cornerAngleTR
> cornerAngleBL = 180 + cornerAngleTR
>
> # Divide to 4 cases:
> if bearing >= cornerAngleTR and bearing < cornerAngleTL:
>     relativeAngle = math.radians(90 - bearing)
>     return (height/2.0)/math.cos(relativeAngle)
> elif bearing >= cornerAngleTL and bearing < cornerAngleBL:
>     relativeAngle = math.radians(180 - bearing)
>     return (width/2.0)/math.cos(relativeAngle)
> elif bearing >= cornerAngleBL and bearing < cornerAngleBR:
>     relativeAngle = math.radians(270 - bearing)
>     return (height/2.0)/math.cos(relativeAngle)
> else:
>     return (width/2.0)/math.cos(math.radians(bearing))
> ```